# linking a subtask in jira with groovy

Tags: groovy, jira

I am working on some groovy-scripts in jira. The script get´s triggered as a postfunction using the scriptrunner plugin.
The code, that produces the error is this one:

```
ComponentAccessor CompAcc = new ComponentAccessor()
SubTaskManager subTaskManager = CompAcc.getSubTaskManager()
...
def subTask = issueManager.createIssue(CompAcc.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser(), issueObject)
subTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink(issue, subTask, usera)
```

where issue is the issue, on which the postfunction was triggered.
The subtask get´s created but not linked to the calling task.

And this is the error:

```
2016-01-11 11:39:39,925 http-bio-8063-exec-19 ERROR asu 699x3972x1 16m4yz4 10.1.21.129 /secure/CommentAssignIssue.jspa [scriptrunner.jira.workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction] *************************************************************************************
2016-01-11 11:39:39,926 http-bio-8063-exec-19 ERROR asu 699x3972x1 16m4yz4 10.1.21.129 /secure/CommentAssignIssue.jspa [scriptrunner.jira.workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction] Script function failed on issue: RQA-7338, actionId: 81, file: /home/qa/Tools/Jira/scripts/CreateDevTestExecutionSubtask.groovy
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.atlassian.jira.config.DefaultSubTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink() is applicable for argument types: (com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueImpl, com.atlassian.jira.ofbiz.IssueGenericValue, com.atlassian.jira.user.DelegatingApplicationUser) values: [RQA-7338, [timespent:null, timeoriginalestimate:7200, project:11400, ...], ...]
Possible solutions: createSubTaskIssueLink(com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue, com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue, com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User), createSubTaskIssueLink(org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue, org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue, com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User)
            at CreateDevTestExecutionSubtask.run(CreateDevTestExecutionSubtask.groovy:212)
```

So what I need to know, is how I can convert *com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueImpl* and *com.atlassian.jira.ofbiz.IssueGenericValue* to *com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue* so that the linking of the subtask works again.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Method `issueManager.createIssue()` is deprecated, it returns GenericValue.
Use `issueManager.createIssueObject()` instead, it returns Issue.

So your code should look like this:

```
def currentUser = CompAcc.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getLoggedInUser()
Issue subTask = issueManager.createIssueObject(currentUser, issueObject)
subTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink(issue, subTask, usera)
```